# Fetching data with PDO

Tags: php, fetch

I'm introducing myself to PDO and i'm trying to fetch data with it. I've done this before, but now i'm getting errors all the time. I've been through this for some hours and didn't find a mistake. If someone could help: my code is:

```
$tabelas_intervalos_afunda = ($con -> query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS afunda_$a
SELECT (L1_forma_tensao_max + L1_forma_tensao_min)/2 as L1_forma_tensao, (L2_forma_tensao_max + L2_forma_tensao_min)/2 as L2_forma_tensao, (L3_forma_tensao_max + L3_forma_tensao_min)/2 as L3_forma_tensao
FROM afundamento
WHERE id > $prevNum AND id < $a');

while($row=$tabelas_intervalos_afunda->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$array_forma_onda_fase1_afund[] = $row['L1_forma_tensao'];
$array_forma_onda_fase2_afund[] = $row['L2_forma_tensao'];
$array_forma_onda_fase3_afund[] = $row['L3_forma_tensao'];
}
```

My problem is that when i `var_dump($array_forma_onda_fase1_afund)`, it returns me "Undefined variable $array_forma_onda_fase1_afund 
NULL

Some additional info: $a is changed always when the loop condition is satisfied. The table afunda_$a is being created as expected, table afundamento exists normally.

Would appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: do a `var_dump($tabelas_intervalos_afunda)`. If it's boolean false or something OTHER than a database result handle, then you've got a failure somewhere.

Comment: Tried this and returned object(PDOStatement) ... ["queryString"] "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS... WHERE id>96 AND id < 122"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a create table statement, which returns no rows.  Then running `fetch` on the result, which doesn't enter the `while` statement.  Hence `$array_forma_onda_fase1_afund` is never defined.

If you want the records you are inserting, you can select them out of the new table or run the original select query.  E.g.:

```
$con->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS afunda_$a
SELECT (L1_forma_tensao_max + L1_forma_tensao_min)/2 as L1_forma_tensao, (L2_forma_tensao_max + L2_forma_tensao_min)/2 as L2_forma_tensao, (L3_forma_tensao_max + L3_forma_tensao_min)/2 as L3_forma_tensao
FROM afundamento
WHERE id > $prevNum AND id < $a');

$tabelas_intervalos_afunda = $con->query("SELECT * FROM afunda_$a");

while($row=$tabelas_intervalos_afunda->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $array_forma_onda_fase1_afund[] = $row['L1_forma_tensao'];
  $array_forma_onda_fase2_afund[] = $row['L2_forma_tensao'];
  $array_forma_onda_fase3_afund[] = $row['L3_forma_tensao'];
}
```

Comment: but the create statement in fact creates the table in my db.

Comment: Yes, it creates the table.  But the result of the query is success or failure, not any records you can loop through.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, i don't get what u meant. U mean i'm creating the table, but can't fetch records?

Comment: You can, you just have to run another query to get them.  See my edit.

Comment: THAT'S IT! Worked fine here! :) Thanks a lot. I thought that when u used CREATE ... SELECT in a query, u already had it selected to fetch. :S